# How to set GAE environment-specific environment variables?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I've got a GAE application in Go using [martini](https://github.com/go-martini/martini). I need to be able to set the `MARTINI_ENV` environment variable to tell martini that it should initialize with production settings. According to the Python docs [you can set environment variables in the app.yaml](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/#Python_The_environment). I didn't see any mention of this in the [Go docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/), but I'm guessing it should work the same.

I need to be able to set the `MARTINI_ENV` environment variable to `production`, but I only want to do that when I'm actually in production (i.e. `!appengine.IsDevAppServer()`). Is there any way to tell `app.yaml` to only do this in running on the non-dev server?

Comment: Did you try and see if it works or not?

Comment: I have not, but obviously I should have. According to @beat-richartz, setting environment variables is **not** supported for Go applications on GAE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GAE in Go has no concept for setting environment variables since these won't be shared across your GAE instances.

Since `martini.Env` is an exported variable though you are able to set it using your own logic. There are multiple ways to do this:

1. Default setting `martini.Env` to production when `MARTINI_ENV` is not present
2. Add your own `config.yaml` to your repo, parse it and set `martini.Env` from there
3. Use a library like [godotenv](https://github.com/joho/godotenv/blob/master/godotenv.go) with its `Read` function, which will read your dotfile instead of loading it into the env.

Comment: I should not have assumed that the environment vars would just work for GAE-Go. Thanks for the alternative ideas. I decided to go with this snippet in my `init()`: `if appengine.IsDevAppServer() { martini.Env = martini.Dev } else { martini.Env = martini.Prod }`

Answer (score 1):

GAE Go does seem to be supporting environment variables now

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig#Go_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables