# how to set environment variables on google appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm trying to set and use an environment variable on google app engine. My app.yaml file looks as below. However when I use os.Getenv("mytoken") I get an empty string instead the actual value I set. Is it a GAE bug?

```
api_version: go1
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
env_variables:
  mytoken: '88786d9b9a0359824'
```

Answer (score 8):

The feature is now documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig#Go_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables). <strike>However, as I have tested just now, it doesn't work on AppEngine. It does work on local server, so don't be fooled.</strike>.

Edit: It works on Google AppEngine. My previous failure is due to a mistake. Consider this:

```
import "os"

var consumer = OAuth1Consumer{
    secret: os.Getenv("secret")
}
```

It does not work if you declare as global variable.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "it does not work if you declare as a global variable"? Your example `consumer` variable is package global so it's unclear what you mean.

Comment: @DaveC I am not sure what went wrong, I am new to Go. The thing is, if I declare the variable as the package global like the sample code, it does not work on AppEngine (however it does work on local dev server). However, if I move the `os.Getenv` inside some function, it works. I have no idea about the internal.

Comment: Based on the link @markdoyle provided below (code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12006), environment variables are not ready until all the init functions are run and I would say same might be applying to the global variable declaration too. It works from a function because by that time environment variables are set.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the GAE Go runtime does **not** support environment variable setting in app.yaml -- see for example [How to set GAE environment-specific environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24585406/how-to-set-gae-environment-specific-environment-variables) and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine-go/qzMbZapLyAU/eKOZzZO14qQJ .

The functionality **is** supported in PHP, per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#PHP_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables ; Java, per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_System_properties_and_environment_variables ; and Python, per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables .

In the Go runtime for App Engine, however -- see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig -- there is simply no equivalent functionality.

I would recommend opening a feature request at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?can=2&q=language=Go&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log (I don't see any equivalent feature request already in the list of 27 open FRs, or else, of course, I would recommend just "starring" the existing FR to register your interest in it).

Comment: Seems this was the issue: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12006 Although currently it only works on dev server and not production.

Comment: @MarkDoyle +1 for the link

Comment: Yep, it's great that the new feature was implemented, just 3 months after this discussion (and it does seem to work in production... but just in the context of a request, after init functions are done  -- roughly as per the discussion on the next question... ah well, better than nothing!-).

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the docs for that field anywhere. I only see it in the python config, not the Go config. It's likely unavailable for go if you're basing this off of the python docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables)